# Clear form fields below the last changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I made a form with multiple selects in it. When you select an option is enables the next select element and updates it with values using Ajax and PHP.

But if you change a previous option it only resets the select field after the one changed and not all the selects below the one which was changed.

So how can I clear all the form elements below the last changed element?

```
<form action="" method="post">
  Year: 
  <select onchange="updateField(this.value, 'brand', 'Year', 'Marke_vozila')">
    <option>Select year..</option>
    %year%
  </select>
  <br />
  Brand: 
  <select id="brand" onchange="updateField(this.value, 'model', 'Marke_vozila', 'Model_vozila')">
  </select>
  <br />
  Model: 
  <select id="model" onchange="updateField(this.value, 'type', 'Model_vozila', 'Tip_vozila')">
  </select>
  <br />
  Type: 
  <select id="type" onchange="updateField(this.value, 'uitvoering', 'Tip_vozila', 'izvedba_vozila')">
  </select>
  <br />
  Uitvoering: 
  <select id="uitvoering">
  </select>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Ajax:

```
    <script>
    function updateField(str, id, prevvalue, value)
    {
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML="";
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","inc/form_rest.php?q="+str+"&prevvalue="+prevvalue+"&value="+value,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the javascript code?

Comment: Tip: _Always_ convert tabs to spaces when pasting any code anywhere on the internet. See how nice it looks now?

Comment: Yes thank you, how do you do that so fast

Comment: There many indenters online, but I just copy/paste in VIM and do `ggVG=` and paste back in here.

Answer (score 0):

Give each of the form elements in order some form of numbered identifier for example inNum=0, inNum=1 etc.

in the onchange handler get the value of this attribute then select each of the elements with the inNum attribute greater then this value and reset its value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the JavaScript code, but you could use the jQuery [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) function to select all remaining siblings.

For example:

```
$(current_field).nextAll('select').val('')
```